# Issue with function str_ireplace

Tags: php

I need replace some words in name so I use `str_ireplace`

code:

```
    $prod['custom_name']['value'] = str_ireplace(
array('woda toaletowa', 'woda perfumowana', 'woda kolońska', 'Spray', 'EDP', 'EDT'),
'TEST',
$prod['custom_name']['value']
);
```

Function work correct but should replace all this words to one word: `TEST`

But TEST display 3 times:

```
PERFUMY DAMSKIE TEST TEST TEST CLINIQUE AROMATICS ELIXIR 10 ML
```

I need display only one time:

```
PERFUMY DAMSKIE TEST CLINIQUE AROMATICS ELIXIR 10 ML
```

Original string:

```
PERFUMY DAMSKIE Woda perfumowana EDP Spray CLINIQUE AROMATICS ELIXIR 10 ML
```

Comment: It is going to replace each instance of the strings in your array with the word TEST not just one of them. What you are asking it to do is not something that the `str_ireplace` function does.

Comment: @Dave so do you have any other solution?